# Why is utserver aka uTorrent Server keeps crashing on ubuntu VPS

Tags: application

I have `ubuntu 12.04 32` bit VPS with `1GB ram`,
I have installed latest utserver `utorrent-server-alpha-v3_3` from `utorrent.com` and using it as daemon

But every now and then `utserver keeps crashing` after few hours for no specific reason.

I have created a cronjob to check whether utserver is running or not , and running it every minute, if its not running then cronjob starts utserver as daemon. and mails me system info .

e.g.
At the time of crash stats

Uptime

```
23:27:07 up 1 day,  1:49,  0 users,  load average: 0.06, 0.13, 0.13
```

/proc/meminfo

```
MemTotal:        1017596 kB
MemFree:          711568 kB
Buffers:           39308 kB
Cached:           100768 kB
SwapCached:          988 kB
Active:            59148 kB
Inactive:         164588 kB
Active(anon):      13944 kB
Inactive(anon):    69848 kB
Active(file):      45204 kB
Inactive(file):    94740 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:       2097148 kB
SwapFree:        2092560 kB
Dirty:                56 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:         82740 kB
Mapped:            11844 kB
Shmem:               132 kB
Slab:              51784 kB
SReclaimable:      22824 kB
SUnreclaim:        28960 kB
KernelStack:         824 kB
PageTables:         6732 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:     2605944 kB
Committed_AS:     465112 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:        9276 kB
VmallocChunk:   34359723260 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:     51200 kB
```

1. why is utserver keeps crashing ?
2. How can i fix it ?

Comment: Check your logs.

Comment: @MichaelHampton any specific logs ?

Comment: Whatever log file your utorrent server is configured to use.

Comment: @EEAA Thanks , i have already specified log file , but at the time of utserver startup, log file gets rewritten, so i have now added to cp log file with timestamp at every restart, just waiting for it to crash now. ill update once i have the log file.